# Keras backend K.switch for loss function error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, switch-statement, backend

I want to implement a custom loss function in keras using keras.backend.switch for a conditional statement, I get this error and really do not know how to solve it,
'''

```
from keras import backend as K 
#q_low and q_high are parameters
def quantile_loss(q_low,q_high, y_p, y):
    e = y_p-y

    loss_low = K.mean(K.maximum(q_low*e, (q_low-1)*e))
    loss_high = K.mean(K.maximum(q_high*e, (q_high-1)*e))

    margin = 45 #constant number
    margin_f = K.cast(margin,'float32')
    cond = K.greater_equal(margin_f,y)
    loss = K.switch(cond,loss_low,loss_high)

    return loss
```

'''
and this is an **error** : " ValueError: Rank of `condition` should be less than or equal to rank of `then_expression` and `else_expression`. ndim(condition)=2, ndim(then_expression)=0 " I appriciate for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation for switch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/switch?version=stable) we can see that this ValueError occurs when the rank of condition is greater than rank of expressions. As far as I know, switch works by checking the value of the condition in each dimension and then applies the appropriate output.

In your case, cond is set to a tensor with the same dimension as y, whereas loss_low and loss_high are both means of maxes which means that they have a dimension of 1, if you have a y with dimension greater than 1 you will trigger this error.

I can't really tell from your code exactly what you are trying to do, but let me suggest the following code snippet based on your code.

```
from keras import backend as K 
#q_low and q_high are parameters
def quantile_loss(q_low,q_high, y_p, y):
    e = y_p-y

    loss_low = K.repeat(K.mean(K.maximum(q_low*e, (q_low-1)*e)), y.shape[0])
    loss_high = K.repeat(K.mean(K.maximum(q_high*e, (q_high-1)*e)), y.shape[0])

    margin = 45 #constant number
    margin_f = K.cast(margin,'float32')
    cond = K.greater_equal(margin_f,y)
    loss = K.switch(cond,loss_low,loss_high)

    return loss
```

I don't have access to the rest of your code, so I can't tell you if this will work, but you can play with it, it should be something like this.

Comment: thanks for your reply @changming. I am confused and couldn't understand these shapes. I do not know why Y has ndim =2. Y is a true label. After changing loss I got this error **in repeat assert ndim(x) == 2 AssertionError**

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't tell you why, but in tensorflow and most other machine learning libraries you can supply vectors/tensors to loss functions which means that Y could have any dimension. If you could provide more code, we might be able to help.

Comment: thanks, I compare them first and at the end mean the result, it works. Do you know what is the order of y_predict and y_true as an input of Keras custom loss function?

Comment: If by order you mean which comes first, keras functions typically put y_true then y_pred. If by order you mean dimensionality, that is decided by you not keras.